# About recent actions

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

When choosing between past simple and present perfect does it matter how recently the action happened ? Or both of them can be used to talk about recent actions ?

Comment: Would you add an example? I'm afraid that this question may be found eligible for close-votes or down-votes by the users in its current format.

Comment: Actually I don't have a certain example right now, I'm just asking generally, is it possible to use past simple to talk about recent actions, Or just present perfect can be used

Comment: Can you make two sentences one for the past and the other for the perfect? This suffices for the example! BTW, In general, I can say yes you can use the past simple. However, note that "Perfect" aspect is a complicated thing. I recommend that you check this awesome post on perfects: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Comment: The recency is not the only determining factor. The time-phrases in the statement are far more important than any absolute recency:  *I **saw** her just a second ago*.  There, **have seen** would not be grammatical. **ago** refers to the event as something that transpired, not in terms of any bearing upon the present.

Comment: @Lucian Sava : OP is asking about *present* perfect.  Your comments are pertinent for the past perfect. The present perfect isn't about sequence but about the past action in relation to the present.

Comment: Oops! I did it, @Tᴚoɯɐuo!